# Using generics to wrap REST api responses in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, generics

I'm calling a REST api with flutter that can return three diferent response types :

```
{
  "data": {
        "amount": 3773.31
      },
      "responseId": "9167712d-f74b-412d-9677-95f7df54fa3a",
      "created": "2023-05-10T08:52:53.5394905Z",
      "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Operación completada con éxito",
        "isSuccess": true
      }
    }
```

When data field contains a value :

```
 {
  "data": {
    "pageSize": 10,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalItems": 20,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 171631,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T14:53:48.4233333",
        "cost": 0.28,
        "minutes": 300,
        "resource": 17
      },
      {
        "id": 171630,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T14:37:32.6233333",
        "cost": 0.43,
        "minutes": 900,
        "resource": 17
      },
      {
        "id": 171629,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T11:55:14.7733333",
        "cost": 0.23,
        "minutes": 120,
        "resource": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 171625,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T10:20:05.3333333",
        "cost": 3.7,
        "minutes": 10800,
        "resource": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 171621,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T09:06:57.4033333",
        "cost": 0.5,
        "minutes": 1200,
        "resource": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 171620,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T08:59:16.5533333",
        "cost": 0.23,
        "minutes": 60,
        "resource": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 171617,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T08:15:36.64",
        "cost": 0.23,
        "minutes": 60,
        "resource": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 171615,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T07:29:29.6633333",
        "cost": 0.95,
        "minutes": 600,
        "resource": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 171614,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-29T07:23:31.4966667",
        "cost": 0.58,
        "minutes": 300,
        "resource": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 171611,
        "dateCreated": "2023-04-28T17:55:30.0366667",
        "cost": 0.28,
        "minutes": 300,
        "resource": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "responseId": "9fd49e0e-8543-4ad7-97ea-53d607c48f05",
  "created": "2023-05-10T08:53:29.382979Z",
  "status": {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "Operación completada con éxito",
    "isSuccess": true
  }
}
```

When No data is returned :

```
 {
      "responseId": "a180068b-01f6-41b3-b19a-0ed2744d3a80",
      "created": "2023-05-10T08:54:17.7533949Z",
      "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Operación completada con éxito",
        "isSuccess": true
      }
    }
```

Following code used by me :

```
class ApiHelper 
           {

              final String apiUrl = "myapp.com";
            
              Future<dynamic> secureGet<T>(
                String url,
                FromJson<T> create,
              ) async {
                final String? token = await SecureStorage().getToken();
            
                Map<String, String> headers = {
                  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
                  HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
                  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
                };
            
                Uri uri = Uri.https(
                  apiUrl,
                  url,
                );
            
                try {
                  final response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
                  return _returnResponse<T>(response, create);
                } on SocketException {
                  throw FetchDataException('Sin conexión');
                } on TimeoutException {
                  throw FetchDataException('Tiempo de espera agotado');
                } on Error catch (e) {
                  throw FetchDataException('Error general: $e');
                }
              }
        
        
    typedef FromJson<T> = T Function(Map<String, dynamic>);
    
    dynamic _returnResponse<T>(Response response, FromJson<T> create) {
      // Makes sure the HTTP request has ended with a 200 succes code
      switch (response.statusCode) {
        case 200:
          {
            // Get JSON object
            var data = json.decode(response.body);
    
            var apiResponse = ApiResponse<T>.fromJson(data, create);
    
            if (!apiResponse.status.isSuccess)
              throw ApiException(apiResponse.status.message);
    
            if (apiResponse.data != null) return create(apiResponse.data);
    
            return apiResponse.data;
          }
        case 400:
          throw BadRequestException(response.body);
        case 401:
        case 403:
          throw UnauthorisedException(response.body);
        case 500:
        case 404:
        default:
          throw FetchDataException(response.statusCode);
      }}
    
    class ApiResponse<T> {
          dynamic data;
          final APIStatus status;
        
          ApiResponse({
            required this.status,
            required this.data,
          });
        
          factory ApiResponse.fromJson(
                  Map<String, dynamic> json, Function(Map<String, dynamic>) create) =>
              new ApiResponse(
                status: APIStatus.fromJson(json["status"]),
                data: json['data'],
              );
        }
    
    
        class OrderListResponse {
          List<Order> results = [];
        
          OrderListResponse({required this.results});
        
          OrderListResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            if (json['items'] != null) {
              json['items'].forEach((v) {
                results.add(new Order.fromJson(v));
              });
            }
          }
        }
}
```

I'm using this code to transform the Order list response to a List of Order classes, I have multiple lists returned by the REST api that I'm wrapping in the same way, is there any better way to create for example a ApiResult<ListResult<>> generic type that I could reuse for any other call returning an object list?

Comment: You seem to be building this by hand. Have you though about tools like Swagger/OpenAPI, that can generate a client for you?